# how can I copy value from one column to another in dataframe conditionally?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], ['Active','Deleted','Active'], [np.nan,2,np.nan]], 
                  columns=list('ABC'))
```

If value of column B is 'Deleted' then I want to copy value for column A into column C else keep it Nan. How can I do it in pandas?

Comment: df['c']=df.a.mask(df.b!='A')

Answer (score 1):

You want `where`:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].where(df['b']=='A')
```